# How to stop javascript fading out element already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, fading

Hi There i have the following code that allows users to swap between 3 tabs, it shows and hides divs by fading them in and out, I would like it so that if the current tab is selected on the nav bar it doesnt fade out and in again, instead i want it to do nothing.

Heres the code:

HTML:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td width="220px">
<p align="left"><table width="220px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

<tr>
<td class="mya_nav" style="border-color: #B23387;">
<a id="show_personal">Personal</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="mya_nav" style="border-color: #00c6ff;">
<a id="show_favourites">Favourites</a>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td class="mya_nav" style="border-color: #00e60b;">
<a id="show_history">History</a>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
</p>

</td>
<td width="675px">

<div id="content">


    <div id="personal" <?php echo $personal_current; ?>>
        <p align="center">Personal</p>

    </div>
    <div id="favourites" <?php echo $favourite_current; ?>>
        <p align="center">Favourites</p>

    </div>
    <div id="history" <?php echo $recent_current; ?>>
        <p align="center">History</p>

    </div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
<script>

    $('p a').click(function(){

        var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();

        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function(){

            $('#'+id).fadeIn(600);
            $('.current').removeClass('current');
            $('#'+id).addClass('current');

        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
<script>

    $('p a').click(function(){

        var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
        if($('.current').attr('id')!=id){
            $('.current').fadeOut(600, function(){
                $('#'+id).fadeIn(600);
                $('.current').removeClass('current');
                 $('#'+id).addClass('current');

            });
        }

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('p a').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).html().toLowerCase();
    if (this.not(':focus')) {
        $('.current').fadeOut(600, function(){
            $('#'+id).fadeIn(600);
            $('.current').removeClass('current');
            $('#'+id).addClass('current');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if *.current* refers to the tab which is currently shown, you should just ignore it when its clicked, by checking if the item clicked is the current one. 
[jQuery's hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) will return true if the item class contains *current* otherwise it returns false.

```
if(!$('#'+id).hasClass('current')){
    $('.current').fadeOut(600, function(){

        $('#'+id).fadeIn(600);
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $('#'+id).addClass('current');

    });
}
```